# Android shared elements transition - wait for animation to finish

Tags: android, animation, android-appcompat, fragmenttransaction, shared-element-transition

I have a list of elements and when I click one, I replace the fragment and use `addSharedElement` for the `FragmentTransaction` to animate the item in the list to become the header in the detail view.

Now I want to populate some details in the detail view, but only AFTER the header animation has finished. Because now, the header animation appears OVER the content and that does not look very good.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: would like to know this as well

Answer (score 4):

I hope I'm not too late. You can retrieve the shared elements transition from `getWindow()` then hook a listener to it.

```
getWindow().getSharedElementEnterTransition().addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {
        // put your code here        
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: This requires Android O, is there a support version as well?